# convert json to string with newline and escape in python

Tags: python, json, api

how to convert using python below payloads:

```
{
    "abc": {
        "i": "1212",
        "j": "add"
    }
}
```

to

```
"{\n\n    \"abc\": {\n        \"i\": \"1212\",\n        \"j\": \"add\"\n    }\n}"
```

Comment: No offense, but I have a suspicion that you might not really understand how escaping quotes in strings works. I still very much believe that none of this is needed for that API. Please actually _try_ if it works with the API and do not just compare it with what (you believe) the string should look like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the optional `indent` parameter of `json.dump` and `json.dumps` to add newlines and indent to the generated string.

```
>>> import json
>>> payload = {
...     "assessmentstatus": {
...         "id": "D37002079003",
...         "value": "In-Progress"
...     }
... }
...
>>> json.dumps(payload)
'{"assessmentstatus": {"id": "D37002079003", "value": "In-Progress"}}'
>>> json.dumps(payload, indent=0)
'{\n"assessmentstatus": {\n"id": "D37002079003",\n"value": "In-Progress"\n}\n}'
>>> json.dumps(payload, indent=2)
'{\n  "assessmentstatus": {\n    "id": "D37002079003",\n    "value": "In-Progress"\n  }\n}'
```

With properly displayed whitespace:

```
>>> print(json.dumps(payload, indent=2))
{
  "assessmentstatus": {
    "id": "D37002079003",
    "value": "In-Progress"
  }
}
```

---

It seems you actually want the string including the enclosing `"` and with all the `"` within the string escaped. This is surprisingly tricky using Python's `repr`, as it always tries to use either `'` or `"` as the outer quotes so that the quotes do *not* have to be escaped.

What seems to work, though, is to just `json.dumps` the JSON string *again*:

```
>>> json.dumps(json.dumps(payload, indent=2))
'"{\\n  \\"assessmentstatus\\": {\\n    \\"id\\": \\"D37002079003\\",\\n    \\"value\\": \\"In-Progress\\"\\n  }\\n}"'
>>> print(json.dumps(json.dumps(payload, indent=2)))
"{\n  \"assessmentstatus\": {\n    \"id\": \"D37002079003\",\n    \"value\": \"In-Progress\"\n  }\n}"
```

Comment: @dev_python It's the same. Python will automatically render `"string with \" quote"` as `'string with " quote'`, i.e. use `'` for the string quotes so it does not have to escape the inner `"`. They are exactly the same strings..

Comment: @dev_python You need _what_? A string with `"` (as it _is_ indeed required by JSON), or a String with enclosing `"` _inside the string itself_ and all the `"` actually escaped?

Comment: @dev_python The first is the printed representation of the string, i.e. how that string could be inputted. Here, all the backslashes are escaped (and thus doubled). The last line is how the string is printed and shows the actual content of the string. But again, I do very much doubt that you actually need _any_ escape sequences at all. If your API is a regular REST API like so many others, just pass the original JSON without any escape sequences!

Comment: @dev_python Okay, so what is the problem? The last string is in exactly that format, or not? Have you actually _tried_ posting this _or_ the original JSON string to the API?

Comment: @dev_python The string _that_ you print is THE SAME string you see when printed. Pass that to the API and see if it works. But again, I do NOT think you need this but should just pass `json.dumps(payload)` to the API, without escaped quotes, and linebreaks should not matter, either. But again, TRY IT WITH THE API, do not just muse on whether the string might look different.

Comment: @dev_python Do not pass the result of `print` but the string you are printing. (Or if that does not work, as I expect, the original string generated by `json` without escaped characters)

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming it has newlines since its in a file

```
with open('file.json') as f: data = json.load(f)
```

Then do what you want with the data

Answer (score 0):

You can save data to a file in JSON format like this

```py
import json

data  = {
    "assessmentstatus": {
        "id": "D37002079003",
        "value": "In-Progress"
    }
}
with open("file.txt", "w") as file:
   json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
```

To retrieve this data you can do

```py
import json

with open("file.txt") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

print(data)
```

JSON is a way to store store data in a string format and be able to parse that data to convert it to actual data.

So trying to convert `"{\n\n "assessmentstatus": {\n "id": "D37002079003",\n "value": "In-Progress"\n }\n}"` on your own is the wrong way to go at this, since JSON is great at doing this.